# I am not getting any output using structures

Tags: c, structure

I'm supposed to print the name of the student with the highest average but my programme doesn't output anything any solutions? When I tried to change %s into %c in printf I got the output successfully but obviously only the first character how do I output the entire string?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "LV2 Z2.h"
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    struct student students[40];
    
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&students[i].name);
    printf("Enter the surname:\n");
    scanf("%s",&students[i].surname);
    printf("Enter the ID:\n");
    scanf("%d",&students[i].studentID);
    printf("Enter the average:\n");
    scanf("%f",&students[i].average);
    printf("Enter the date:\n");
    scanf("%s",&students[i].date);
        
        
    }
    float max = 0;
    int bestStudent = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     if(students[i].average > max) {
    max = students[i].average;
    bestStudent = i;
    }
    }
    printf("Student : %s %s ima najbolji prosjek",students[bestStudent].name,students[bestStudent].surname);
    return 0;
}



struct student 
{
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    int studentID;
    float average;
    char date[100];
    
};
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&students[i].name);` is never correct. You want `students[i].name` because name is either an array or a pointer to char.

Comment: BTW what is the definition of `struct student`

Comment: Definition of student is also pasted here.

Comment: It is in wrong order.

Comment: When I remove the & the programme stops working after I enter the name of the first student.

Comment: My mistake I might've formatted it uncorrectly here I have made a seperate header where I placed my student structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your header file, I ran your program. I had to move your structure definition to be above main so that main recognizes it. Else, it won't compile. Did you previous have the structure defined in your header file, but you just moved it into main for the purposes of showing us? If so, that would cause your program not to work.

I also changed your scanf()'s involving %s. The name of an array evaluates as the address of the first element i.e.

```
int myArray[20]; // myArray evaluates as &myArray[0]
```

So, remove the & symbol with all of your scanf's involving %s.

After making these changes, I ran your program and it seemed to work fine.

MAIN

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    int studentID;
    float average;
    char date[100];

};

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    struct student students[40];

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name:\n");
        scanf("%s", students[i].name);
        printf("Enter the surname:\n");
        scanf("%s", students[i].surname);
        printf("Enter the ID:\n");
        scanf("%d", &students[i].studentID);
        printf("Enter the average:\n");
        scanf("%f", &students[i].average);
        printf("Enter the date:\n");
        scanf("%s", students[i].date);


    }
    float max = 0;
    int bestStudent = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (students[i].average > max) {
            max = students[i].average;
            bestStudent = i;
        }
    }
    printf("Student : %s %s ima najbolji prosjek", students[bestStudent].name, students[bestStudent].surname);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
4
Enter the name:
John
Enter the surname:
Smith
Enter the ID:
111
Enter the average:
90
Enter the date:
2/6/21
Enter the name:
Sarah
Enter the surname:
Jones
Enter the ID:
222
Enter the average:
95
Enter the date:
2/6/21
Enter the name:
Mike
Enter the surname:
Johnson
Enter the ID:
333
Enter the average:
80
Enter the date:
2/6/21
Enter the name:
Bob
Enter the surname:
Sampson
Enter the ID:
444
Enter the average:
70
Enter the date:
2/6/21
Student : Sarah Jones ima najbolji prosjek
```

Comment: Even when i deleted the & from string scanning It still couldn't run and then I changed the name of the header file and now it works. Don't know how that happened because when I use %c it still printed out the 1st letter of the name and surname...

Comment: What is in the header file?

Comment: The structure student.